# Sum of any two prime numbers except the prime number 2 is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

**(a) For every odd natural number, there is a different natural number such that their sum is even.**

$$(\forall x): (\neg \text{Even}(x) \rightarrow (\forall y): (y \neq x \rightarrow \text{Even}(x+y)).$$

**Alternate Solution: $\forall x (\neg \text{Even}(x) \rightarrow \exists y (y \neq x \land \text{Even}(x+y))$**

**(b) The sum of any two prime number except the prime number 2 is even.**

**1.** $(\forall x, y):((x \neq 2 \land y \neq 2) \rightarrow ([\text{Prime}(x) \land \text{Prime}(y)) \rightarrow \text{Even}(x+y))).$

**2.** $(\forall x, y):((\text{Prime}(x) \land \text{Prime}(y) \land \text{Even}(x+y)) \rightarrow (x \neq 2 \land y \neq 2)).$

I am not sure which one of the logical statements is correct for **(b)**, I think it's **2.** because the first statement will be vacuously true even if $x$ and $y$ are primes not equal to $2$.

Is my reasoning correct? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Can you type out (2) using words? What does it actually say in English? (Forget the problem statement, just imagine you came across (2) without the context of this exercise. Translate it as you would any other expression.)

Comment: (2) If x and y are prime and their sum is even, then both x and y cannot be equal to 2. I interpreted it as an only if statement, the sum of 2 primes can only be even, only if both are not equal to 2. Do the 2 statements have the same meaning as the one in the problem statement?

Comment: @user594831 And this is obviously false because $2+2=4$ is even

Comment: Yes, but the question only asked to convert the bolded problem statements to logical statements, they didn't mention disproving them .

Comment: About (a), which variable in the sentence you wrote represents the "different natural number". Does the quantifier on this variable match the way "different natural number" is quantified in the sentence?

Comment: $1$ means (although there should be paranthesis to make it more clear) : If $x$ and $y$ are both different from $2$, then if $x$ and $y$ are prime , then $x+y$ is even. And this is the correct formulation of the statement.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the statement to include the quantifier y, but not sure if (b) is correct

Comment: Your initial formula already had a quantifier on $y$ (just closer to where $y$ is first used). Now your sentence quantifies over $y$ twice. The point of my comment was not that you forgot the quantifier.

Comment: @halrankard2 I edited the statement, it's okay to use the quantifier closer to where it is required right? I think my answer for (a) is correct?

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I included the paranthesis, (1) is correct  and (2) is wrong because of the counter example 2+2=4, right?

Comment: @user594831 right

Comment: @user594831 The placement of the quantifier was fine from the beginning. It's the actual quantifier itself that is the issue. In your formula, $y$ represents the "different natural number" and the sentence says *there is* a different natural number. What your formula says is "For any $x$, if $x$ is not even then, for any $y$, if $y\neq x$ then $x+y$ is even."

Comment: @halrankard2 Thanks, so it should be there exists y instead of for all y, I edited the soltuon for (a) , it's is correct now right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a supplementary answer on $(a)$. This isn't what you originally asked, but there are errors here too.

First, I recap the comments. Your original solution was
$$
\forall x(\neg E(x)\rightarrow \forall y (y\neq x\rightarrow E(x+y)))
$$
(I'm using $E$ for the Even predicate).

So right away one can tell this is probably wrong because the quantifier on $y$ doesn't match up. The original sentence says *there is* a different natural number, while the formula has $\forall y$.

However, there is more to fixing this than simply changing $\forall$ to $\exists$, because these two quantifiers act differently when attached to implications. Consider the following two statements:

1. $x+y$ is even for every $y$ different from $x$.
2. $x+y$ is even for some $y$ different from $x$.

The first attempt expresses option 1 with the clause "$\forall y(y\neq x\rightarrow E(x+y)$" or, in other words, "for all $y$, if $y\neq x$ then $x+y$ is even".  So this accurately describes (1). But, of course, you don't want (1), you want (2). So what happens if I just change $\forall$ to $\exists$? I get:

$$
\exists y (y\neq x\rightarrow E(x+y))
$$

So does this accurately express (2)? Translating directly, I get "there is a $y$ such that if $y\neq x$ then $x+y$ is even". This does not have the same meaning as "$x+y$ is even for some $y\neq x$". So one needs to think about how to accurately express "there is a $y$ different from $x$ such that $x+y$ is even".

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now, am I right in saying that x+y is even only if y is different from x. So, I would have to swap Even(x+y) and (y not equal to x) to get the statement: ∃((+)→≠)

Comment: This still doesn't do it. This says "there is a $y$ such that if $x+y$ is even then $y\neq x$". So I can make this true by finding a $y$ such that $x+y$ is not even, so that the implication is vacuously true. So this is not expressing that there is a $y$ different from $x$ with $x+y$ even. Expressing this via implications is not the most natural way. I know that I want an existential $\exists y$...ok good. Now what properties to I want this $y$ to have? Think about logical symbols other than implications.

Comment: Okay, so it should be ∀( ¬Even()→∃(  ≠  ∧ Even(+)) ), I always get confused between using the → and ∧ symbol.

Comment: Yes that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For a) consider for example x = 3. Is it true that for all natural y, x+y is even?

For b2) consider x, y = 2. Would then statement be true?

For b1) what happens if x = 7 and y = 2?

UPD: However, all of these maybe just a minute of dumbness from me.